# Unable to debug the application in VS 2010 , error thrown: cannot open the pdb file

Tags: c

Following is the error string :

Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\Automation.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\libxml2.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsock32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2help.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\iconv.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\zlib1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\hasp_windows_37517.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\sntl_licgen_windows.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Automation.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
First-chance exception at 0x007ff9ba in Automation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x007ff82f in Automation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
The program '[400] Automation.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Earlier with the same configuration i was successfully able to debug the app.

Comment: Is the application compiled in Debug mode?

Comment: It doesn't have to be debug-compiled for pdb-output (something MS *finally* did right).

Comment: The very first line of your output log suggests something counter to you question title: "Automation.exe': Loaded 'D:\Automation\debug\Automation.exe', **Symbols loaded.**" Are you running this under the debugger, and if so, what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: unable to see the stack trace. the option stack trace inside debugging->windows is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last lines of your log suggest your application is crashing on startup.

> First-chance exception at 0x007ff9ba in Automation.exe: **0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.** First-chance exception at 0x007ff82f in Automation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. The program '[400] Automation.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Set a breakpoint on main and then step through your code to see where it crashes. Under VS you should actually see a dialog when the exception is thrown. There you can click `Debug` to stop execution and see the stack trace.

Comment: thanks a lot RedX , my application was actually crashing and stepping over tracked down the actual issue of crash.